# Add variable types in .pyx file (Python)

Tags: python, types, cython

I am trying to compile a module using Cython, in order to speed it up.

The speed up is not bad, but Cython's tutorial points out it can be even better when using static typing (see http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/cythonize.html#determining-where-to-add-types).

Now I have used the

```
cython -a myscript.pyd
```

command to see where it would be good to add types, and everywhere I declare variables pretty much the lines of codes are highlighted in yellow indicating I could potentially add variable types there.

The issue I have is that it only seems to be possible to do this inside a function. For example, some of my yellow-highlighted lines in the code are

```
a = np.zeros(len(b))
word = 'pref'
```

So in the .pyx file I changed that to

```
float a = np.zeros(len(b))
char word = 'pref'
```

Now this does not work. I cannot run or compile this. So how can I add variables types when not inside a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to tell cython that this variable will get a static type with `cdef`. Second you are trying to assign an array to a single float variable. You have to use a type that is compatible with a numpy array. [Numpy](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/strings.html) has a C-backend that defines array types which can be used in Cython. The correct way to declare a type for your array would be.

```
cimport numpy as np
cdef np.ndarray[np.double_t] a = np.zeros(len(b))
```

Multi character strings are saved in arrays in C. A single `char` variable can only hold one letter. There is a page in the [Cython tutorial](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html) how to handle python strings in cython

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `cdef`:

```
cdef char word
c = 'pref'
cdef int i,b etc..
```

I f you look in those docs you linked to:

*Python function calls can be expensive – in Cython doubly so because one might need to convert to and from Python objects to do the call. In our example above, the argument is assumed to be a C double both inside f() and in the call to it, yet a Python float object must be constructed around the argument in order to pass it.
Therefore Cython provides a syntax for declaring a C-style function, the cdef keyword:*

```
cdef double f(double x) except? -2:
    return x**2-x
```

Comment: Or cpdef, depending on need.

Comment: @WilliamMcBrine, yes depending on what you wanted to do